# PHP 5.3 Coding Standards: Anonymous functions in templates

Tags: php, coding-style, anonymous-function

I can not seem to find any documents stating if anonymous functions in templates are a good idea when templating HTML with PHP. I have the following code for example:

```
<html><body>
<?
$listMethod = function($items)
{
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?foreach ($items as $item):?>
            <li><?=$item?></li>
        <?endforeach;?>
    </ul>
<?
};
?>
<?=$listMethod(array('1','2','3'))?>
<p> AND </p>
<?=$listMethod(array('a','b','c'))?>
</body></html>
```

Is this a good or bad way to create templates in PHP?

Comment: In fact, you can make your templates as ugly as you wish, as long as you'e only one who have to mess with it.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: :)) true, but it whont get you anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad bad way , it will be realy hard to debug them, edit, find, ... . You could include a template_functions.php file at the top of you're template and store all template related functions/helpers there .

---

Edit

Allso do not use short tags if you're into conding standards , most hosting companyes will allow them ( short tags ) but a few whont so you'll have problems .

Answer (score 1):

Look at views as something that's just for output, nothing else.

Everything except **echo**, **if** and **loops**  should concern you if in there. (**Especially** function definitions)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good or bad way to create templates in PHP?

That depends on whether or not you're intending to re-use that function in more than just one view. If you do, you might want to give the function a name, and put it somewhere so that multiple views can use it. If you don't want to use that function ever again, an anonymous function would do. Then again, I find anonymous functions to be less expressive than normal functions, so I don't think I'd use them for this precise purpose.

It's personal preference, though, and there's no consensus on this being good or bad.

Answer (score 0):

Why scratch your left year with your right hand, as long as you have a left hand to do it? Best way is to define this as a classic function somewhere (myLeftyHelpers.php or whatever file). Although you made me wonder, I really do belive that the role of anonymus functions(if they work in PHP, never tried) are meant to act as function pointers, meaning that this way you can pass a function as a parameters to another function, that's the way I see them used. If someone thinks I am worng please correct me.